# page resizing issue.the child div not resize like parent div

Tags: css, html

i am now struggle with a resizing issue. in my page i have a main div and  inside that div i have several div.the main div is now re-sizable but the child div contents are gone out side of the main div when i resize the page .with out scrollbar how can i solve this problem

```css
 .contentcolumn {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-left:108px;
    margin-right:48px;
    height: calc(100% - (150px + 50PX));
   
}
        body,html{
            
   
    height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<div class="contentcolumn">
  <div>hai</div>
    <div>haihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihai</div>
    <div>haihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihai</div>
    <div>haihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihai</div>
    <div>haihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihai</div>
    <div>haihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihai</div>
    <div>haihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihai</div>
    <div>haihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihai</div>
    <div>hai</div>
    <div>hai</div>
    <div>hai</div>
    <div>hai</div>
    
    <div>hai</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **word-break** to your element

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

```css
.contentcolumn {
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        margin-left:108px;
        margin-right:48px;
        height: calc(100% - (150px + 50PX));
       word-break: break-all;
    }
```

```html
<div class="contentcolumn">
  <div>hai</div>
    <div>haihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihai</div>
    <div>haihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihai</div>
    <div>haihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihai</div>
    <div>haihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihai</div>
    <div>haihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihai</div>
    <div>haihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihai</div>
    <div>haihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihaihai</div>
    <div>hai</div>
    <div>hai</div>
    <div>hai</div>
    <div>hai</div>
    
    <div>hai</div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The div does resize but due to the text being a long uninterrupted string it overflows out of the div.

A solution would be to use `word-break: break-all` on the `.contentcolumn` which would move the overflowing text onto a new line.